# Date type to long milli seconds

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a Date Field pulled from a excel in kettle. How to convert it to long milli seconds in my job?
Thanks

Comment: how does the date look like ?? could you post something you hve tried ??

Comment: The date looks like "12/19/13 0:00" in the excel.
In my kettle job I extracted this column as Date with a format.

Comment: The date looks like "12/19/13 0:00" in the excel.
In my kettle job I extracted this column as Date with a format.
Next Step is "JSON output". The output looks like. {"logDate":"12/19/13 0:00"}. Next step I tried to convert this to long using Modify java script value. But getting error.

Comment: what's the exact error ? and how did you try when you got the error ?

Comment: Actually I am not getting error. In "Modify Java Script Value" step I am doing data.logDate = new Date(data.logDate).getTime(). Yet output is {"logDate":"12/19/13"}. I tried setting data.logDate = "hello world". Yet output is {"logDate":"12/19/13"}. I commented all lines yet same output. Some thing wrong.

Comment: It is working now. I was looking at wrong log file. Fix is -  data.logDate = str2date(data.logDate, "MM/dd/yy").getTime(). Thanks @mlwn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Modify Javascript value" step to do this like below. Here logDate to begin with is like "12/13/13".
data.logDate = str2date(data.logDate, "MM/dd/yy").getTime(). The output of this step will be like {"logDate":1386921600000}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below formula to convert the date in to  milli second.

```
=TIMEVALUE(date)*86400000
```

Take the decimal value of the time and multiply it by 1000 (milliseconds) and 60 (seconds) and 60 (minutes) and 24 (hours).

Hope this helps

Comment: Your technique is giving different long value. For date 12/13/2013 Actual is 3470256000000 Expected is 1389600000000

Answer (score 0):

The User-Defined Java Expression step is faster than the Java Script step, you can use this expression to parse the string into milliseconds:

new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse(logDate).getTime()